# x2go on mac -- need multiple x2go windows at the same time -- how?

Tags: xquartz, x2go

We use x2go from individual machines to the shared server.

Those using MS Windows can start multiple x2go windows, on their local machine, all connected to the server at the same time.  This allows them to do multiple different things on the server at the same time, comparing different files, etc.  (We are doing a chip and need to have large waveforms up, so multiple things in a single x2go window is not effective).

However, those using MacOS seem unable to open multiple x2go windows at the same time.  Mac seems to limit to only one x2go window open.

Any ideas how to fix this?  Is it an inherent limitation of the Mac implementation?  Or.. is there some XQuartz thing we can do.. or?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to start multiple sessions from the ordinary MacOS graphical interface. However, you can start multiple sessions from the command line by invoking the x2goclient with the --session argument. The session argument is the name of your session in the normal session window.

/Applications/x2goclient.app/Contents/MacOS/x2goclient --session="stellar-obs 34A"

and after logging in there and getting situated, brazenly open another Terminal on your Mac and do:

/Applications/x2goclient.app/Contents/MacOS/x2goclient --session="helena"

and in my case, running Ventura 13.2.1 on an M1 with X2Go Client v. 4.1.2.2 (Qt - 4.8.7), it works!